# New dataframe of means across dataframes

Tags: r

I have five dataframes of about 60 columns that I need to combine. They each have the same columns and I'm combining them with their means since they represent the same value. The issue isn't the ability to combine them, but doing so efficiently. Here is sample data/code:

```
#reproducible random data
set.seed(123)

dat1 <- data.frame( a = rnorm(16), b = rnorm(16), c = rnorm(16), d = rnorm(16), e = rnorm(16), f = rnorm(16))
dat2 <- data.frame( a = rnorm(16), b = rnorm(16), c = rnorm(16), d = rnorm(16), e = rnorm(16), f = rnorm(16))
dat3 <- data.frame( a = rnorm(16), b = rnorm(16), c = rnorm(16), d = rnorm(16), e = rnorm(16), f = rnorm(16))

#This works but is inefficient

final_data<-data.frame(a=rowMeans(cbind(dat1$a,dat2$a,dat3$a)),
                       b=rowMeans(cbind(dat1$b,dat2$b,dat3$b)),
                       c=rowMeans(cbind(dat1$c,dat2$c,dat3$c)),
                       d=rowMeans(cbind(dat1$d,dat2$d,dat3$d)),
                       e=rowMeans(cbind(dat1$e,dat2$e,dat3$e)),
                       f=rowMeans(cbind(dat1$f,dat2$f,dat3$f))
)
#what results should look like
head(final_data)
#             a           b          c           d            e           f
# 1 0.573813625  0.17695841 -0.1434628 -0.53673101  0.353906578  0.24262067
# 2 0.135689926 -0.69206908  0.2888584 -0.37215810 -0.038298083 -0.23317107
# 3 0.004068807  0.44666945  0.5205118  0.09587453 -0.308528454  0.30516883
# 4 0.347100292  0.02401646  0.1409754 -0.15931120  0.587047386 -0.08684867
# 5 0.006529998  0.09010946  0.4932670  0.62606230 -0.005235813 -0.36967000
# 6 0.240225778 -0.45824825 -0.5000004  0.66131121  0.619480608  0.55650611
```

The issue here is that I don't want to rewrite `a=rowMeans(cbind(dat1$a,dat2$a,dat3$a))` for each of 60 columns in the new data frame. Can you think of a good way to go about this?

EDIT: I'm going to accept the following answer since it allows me to set the columns to apply it over-

```
final_data1<-as.data.frame(sapply(colnames(dat1),function(i)
    rowMeans(cbind(dat1[,i],dat2[,i],dat3[,i]))))

> identical(final_data1,final_data)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I would add `set.seed` here so we could match desired output more easily.

Comment: Updated the post with set.seed, hope @Jason doesn't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sapply(colnames(dat1),function(i)
  rowMeans(cbind(dat1[,i],dat2[,i],dat3[,i])))
```

Comment: Yes sir. That works.

`final_data1<-as.data.frame(sapply(colnames(dat1),function(i)
    rowMeans(cbind(dat1[,i],dat2[,i],dat3[,i]))))

 identical(final_data1,final_data)

[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 3):

I would combine all data sets into one data set using `rbind` and then compute column means using`data.table` (for speed)

```
library(data.table)
df <- rbind(dat1, dat2, dat3)
indx <- seq_len(nrow(df)) %% nrow(dat1)  
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = indx]
```

The nicest thing about this approach is that once all the data sets combined within one data set, you can calculate various functions (not just `mean`) without the need of calling `cbind` each time. It is also easy to run operations on specific columns using the `.SDcols` argument, for example

```
cols <- names(df)[c(1,3:4)]
df[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = cols, by = indx]
```

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your comment that you want to specify column names.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
(dat1+dat2+dat3)/3
```

Or, to first select/reorder a subset of the columns, and *then* add the resulting data.frames, you could do this:

```
jj <- letters[1:6]
Reduce(`+`, lapply(list(dat1,dat2,dat3), `[`, jj))/3
```

Comment: Are you kidding me? I feel ashamed now.

Comment: Yep, I was kidding *you* ;)

Comment: Well, I should have said that I need to be able to specify the columns to use. My apologies

Comment: @Jason No problem. Have edited my answer to give the extension of my first answer to the case you just mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
mapply(function(x,y,z) rowMeans(cbind(x,y,z)), dat1, dat2, dat3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is another trial.

```
lst <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
bind <- do.call(cbind, lst)
sapply(colnames(dat1), function(x) {
  rowMeans(bind[, colnames(bind) == x])
})
a           b            c           d           e            f
[1,] -0.69651939 -0.43495675  0.267416865  0.48329853  0.61255811 -1.505583996
[2,] -0.07074860  0.09862994 -0.003961269  0.73806156 -0.80865458 -1.367104216
[3,] -0.90342272 -0.62873624  0.260394162 -0.28607083  1.10855838 -1.073984557
[4,] -0.05890636  0.81463842 -0.227212609  0.21552260 -0.20440539 -0.071603144
[5,]  0.34237648  0.11332086 -0.673674065 -0.17747223  0.21157555  0.641724519
[6,] -0.15563697 -0.10291304  0.334530993 -0.42936296  0.16148849  0.635475661
[7,]  0.05404325  1.36754458 -0.375816720  0.20686341  0.78680115  0.553046376
[8,] -0.73117177  0.92057378  0.501956982  0.70190124  0.69835069  0.350644246
[9,]  0.17803759  0.04951559 -1.098479453 -0.26502658 -0.61354619  1.027449014
[10,] -0.48196619  0.11175892 -0.179521990 -0.75229105  0.31444472  0.083272675
[11,] -0.32993871 -0.01253952 -0.585723144  0.70656176 -0.32358449 -0.252437496
[12,] -0.96078171  1.44073015  0.221025206  0.30641093 -0.89929299  0.005243541
[13,]  0.03855730 -0.07904409  0.579366082  0.87307855  0.08949804  0.023818143
[14,] -0.28243416  0.68603908 -0.046795603 -0.09192619  0.26275774  0.594420728
[15,] -0.83591175 -0.62040012  0.598931246 -0.22719000  0.50836421 -0.135153053
[16,] -0.55951822  0.42339116  0.162560131 -0.08010072  0.79547162 -0.334898253
```